# current focussed field of a TClientDataSet

Tags: delphi, tclientdataset

I have a situation where I have to allow the user to update **either of** 2 fields of a dbgrid(connected to a CDS) persisting the last entered one. So (after user enters data) I need to get the **current focused control**, so that i will remove the previous field data if it has any.  I also have other fields apart from these two.

It was insisted not to use any grid related events, i have to use only CDS event to achieve this.

Thanks in advance,
Vijay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the field's OnChange event, and just clear the other field value if any:

Something like this:

```
TForm1.cdsField1Change(Sender: TField);
begin
  if not Sender.IsNull then
    cdsField2.Clear;
end;

TForm1.cdsField2Change(Sender: TField);
begin
  if not Sender.IsNull then
    cdsField1.Clear;
end;
```

Comment: Correct principle, but will that code not cause an infinite loop (field1 alters field2 alters field1 ad infinitum)?

Comment: Thanks for that @Stuart, I now changed the code to prevent the StartOveflow on my answer.

Comment: Thanks for @jachguate and @Stuart it worked as expected, only one more condition Sender.Name was added by me since there were some more fields apart from these two.